# How to display X-Axis and Y-Axis values when move the mouse?

Tags: c#, charts

How can I display the values of X-Axis and Y-Axis when the mouse is moved
anywhere within the chart area (like the picture)?

[image]

The `HitTest` method can not be applied for moving or it can only be applied for clicking on the chart?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

[The tooltip shows data outside the real area data drawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9Lnt.png)

Comment: If this is a WinForms application then you can handle the `Control.MouseMove` event. The `MouseEventArgs` parameter contains X and Y properties.

Comment: Yes, I used Chart in WinForms.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 3):

Actually the `Hittest` method works just fine in a `MouseMove`; its problem is that it will only give a hit when you are actually **over** a `DataPoint`.

The `Values` on the `Axes` can be retrieved/converted from pixel coordinates by these axis-functions:

```
ToolTip tt = null;
Point tl = Point.Empty;

private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (tt == null )  tt = new ToolTip();

    ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];

    if (InnerPlotPositionClientRectangle(chart1, ca).Contains(e.Location))
    {

        Axis ax = ca.AxisX;
        Axis ay = ca.AxisY;
        double x = ax.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);
        double y = ay.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y);
        string s = DateTime.FromOADate(x).ToShortDateString();
        if (e.Location != tl)
            tt.SetToolTip(chart1, string.Format("X={0} ; {1:0.00}", s, y));
        tl = e.Location;
    }
    else tt.Hide(chart1);
}
```

Note that they will not work **while** the chart is busy laying out the chart elements or **before** it has done so. `MouseMove` is fine, though.

[image]

Also note that the example displays the raw data while the x-axis labels show the data as `DateTimes`. Use

```
string s = DateTime.FromOADate(x).ToShortDateString();
```

or something  similar to convert the values to dates!

The check for being inside the actual plotarea uses these two useful functions:

```
RectangleF ChartAreaClientRectangle(Chart chart, ChartArea CA)
{
    RectangleF CAR = CA.Position.ToRectangleF();
    float pw = chart.ClientSize.Width / 100f;
    float ph = chart.ClientSize.Height / 100f;
    return new RectangleF(pw * CAR.X, ph * CAR.Y, pw * CAR.Width, ph * CAR.Height);
}

RectangleF InnerPlotPositionClientRectangle(Chart chart, ChartArea CA)
{
    RectangleF IPP = CA.InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF();
    RectangleF CArp = ChartAreaClientRectangle(chart, CA);

    float pw = CArp.Width / 100f;
    float ph = CArp.Height / 100f;

    return new RectangleF(CArp.X + pw * IPP.X, CArp.Y + ph * IPP.Y,
                            pw * IPP.Width, ph * IPP.Height);
}
```

If you want to you can cache the `InnerPlotPositionClientRectangle`; you need to do so when you change the data layout or resize the chart.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works well. However, it has a problem: When I move the mouse outside the chart, the area contains real data drawn, the tooltip also shows data, this is not really thing I need. Do you have solution for that?

Comment: Ah, yes. You are right. We need to add a check for being inside a Charatarea's Innerplotposition.. I have updated the answer..

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..